# Cannot choose file by dropping file on area outside the button but inside input only when using Shadow DOM

Tags: javascript, file, google-chrome, shadow-dom, custom-element

In chrome, following input element can be dragged and dropped to the bottom area of the input.
I expect this behavior.

```
<input type="file" class="input-file">

<style>
.input-file {
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    margin: 10px;
}
</style>
```

However, it is different inside Shadow DOM.
Following input element can be dragged and dropped to only the "choose file" button located the left top area of the input.
Dropped file is opened not chosen when file is droppped to the bottom area of the input.

```
customElements.define("foo-bar", class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.attachShadow({mode: "open"}).innerHTML = `
            <input type="file" class="input-file">

            <style>
            .input-file {
                display: block;
                width: 300px;
                height: 300px;
                border: 1px solid red;
                margin: 10px;
            }
            </style>
        `
    }
})
document.body.innerHTML = "<foo-bar></foo-bar>"
```

I think that this is a bug caused by events not being notified outside of Shadow DOM.

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround is to process the [`drop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API/File_drag_and_drop#Process_the_drop) event.

```
this.shadowRoot.querySelector( 'input' ).ondrop = ev => {
    console.log( 'dropped in', ev.dataTransfer.items.length  )
    for ( var i = 0 ; i < ev.dataTransfer.items.length ; i++ ) {
        if (ev.dataTransfer.items[i].kind === 'file') {
            var file = ev.dataTransfer.items[i].getAsFile()
            console.log( 'file[' + i + '].name = ' + file.name )
        }
    }
    ev.preventDefault()
}
```

Don't forget to invoke the `preventDefault()` method to abort the file opening.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but the bug is still not fixed. I found a CSS workaround for Chrome to use the input button instead of the input for the draft & drop. In my case I used an opacity of 0 so the design is not an issue for me.

```js
customElements.define("foo-bar", class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor(){
        super()
        this.attachShadow({mode: "open"}).innerHTML = `
            <input type="file" />

            <style>
            input {
                display: block;
                width: 300px;
                height: 300px;
                border: 1px solid red;
                margin: 10px;
            }
            
            input::-webkit-file-upload-button {
                width: 300px;
                height: 300px;
            }
            </style>
        `
    }
})
```

```html
<foo-bar></foo-bar>
```